Battery Charging Circuit - What is the operational analysis of device Q1?


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
V1 is a 24 volt dc 210 milliamp power adapter. V2 is a 14.4 volt nominal nicad battery in a handheld vacuum. V1 is almost 30 volts open circuit. When charging with the LED on this drops closer to 16 volts which is only six or seven tenths of a volt higher than the battery charging voltage. The voltage at the top of R1 is 5.8 volts and across LED is 1.8 volts.
EDIT (Correct Circuit Now) - Q1 is shown in circuit as a PNP transistor. I verified it is PNP 3906. How would it operate in circuit maybe to shut off the LED when the battery V2 is fully charged?

I couldn't help but notice that you haven't accepted the answer. Did it not address your question?

I voted up the answer but I don't find the simulation compelling. The model for the source and battery with internal resistance is probably necessary to give complete understanding of how the base current is dependent on the current through R2 over time as the battery voltage increases and the charge current decreases.

Ok, no problem.  The base current is highly unaffected by the source resistances of either supply though - not with its 50 kOhm resistor.  The point of the circuit is the relative voltage levels; i.e. whether or not the BE junction is forward biased. When V2 reaches a level beyond that voltage drop, the transistor no longer conducts from V1 to the LED.

Well, when the battery voltage reaches a diode drop (VBE of Q1) less than V1, the transistor will turn off, blocking current to the LED.
So, if V1 is 16 V when loaded, the battery will charge to maybe 15.3 V, at which point the LED will turn off.
It looks like this in a simulation:


